# How to keep Git stash index unchanged when adding new stash

Tags: git

Let's imagine my branch have two stash.

When I save another stash the stash index gets changed. 0 becomes 1 , 1 becomes 2 and new stash set to 0.

is it possible to keep the stash index unchanged when I add new stash? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible.

You can get somewhat close, using `git stash create` *without* running a subsequent `git stash store`.  You must then create some *other* name to hold the stash commits (remember, `git stash` makes commits, just like `git commit`!) so as not to disturb the `refs/stash` reference nor any of its reflog entries.

The `git stash apply` command accepts any reference that points to a commit that is "stash-like".  Any commit created by `git stash create` is of course very stash-like since it *is* a stash commit.

As a very rough example:

```
hash=$(git stash create)
if [ "$hash" == "" ]; then
    echo "nothing to save!"
else
    git update-ref refs/private-stash $hash
    echo "new private-stash created"
fi
```

and later:

```
git stash apply refs/private-stash
git update-ref -d refs/private-stash
```

Comment: "not possible" is a strong phrase, but in practice I don't think most people would want to do what's required.  See my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

It would take a fair amount of scripting.  In practice, I second torek's answer ("No"), but for completeness here is what you'd have to do:

First, you'd need to make note of all the commit ID's pointed to by current stash reflog along with their subject messages.  You should do this before creating the new stash.  (This whole mess is quite a bit messier if the stash has already been created.)  One way to do this is

```
git reflog stash --format=%h %gs
```

Actually what you want to do, though, is have these recorded somewhere for later reference.  An "easy enough" way to do that is

```
git reflog stash --format='-m "%gs" %h' |xargs -n 3 git update-ref --create-reflog temp_stash
```

The entries in the `temp-stash` reflog will be reversed compared to the `stash` reflog, but that'll come out in the wash shortly.

Now that `temp_stash` is keeping track of your stash entries, you need to wipe out the stash ref and its reflog.

```
git update-ref -d refs/stash
```

Now you can create your new stash.

```
git stash
```

and then pull the stored reflog entries back in from temp_stash

```
git reflog temp_stash --format='-m "%gs" %h' |xargs -n 3 git update-ref --create-reflog refs/stash
```

This *again* reverses the order of reflog entries as it goes, so the reflog is put back "in order", with the new stash you created getting pushed to the end.

Comment: Yeah, and there's one more way using the `git update-ref` operation to sort of rotate the reflogs, but that's equally painful.